# Pre-loading array values into a function

Tags: php

I am not sure if I am doing this correctly,pre-loading my array values for coins with the function defaultcoindload();

```
defaultcoindload();
function defaultcoindload()
{
/*Have the coin loads up to a maximum of a 1.00 dollar in value:
An associative array-ID key is associated with  value(ID is Nickels with value of 20).
$money = array("Nickels"=>20, "Dimes"=>10, "Quarters"=>10);
The array code for $money above  is  the same as the array code below,
with the difference being the structure and the ID keys can be accessed in a script*/

if ($money < 1.00)
{
echo "money";
}
else if($money = $insertcoins[$selection])
{
echo "$selection";
}


 $money['Nickels'] = "20";
 $money['Dimes'] = "10";
 $money['Quarters'] = "10";
 echo "The value of Nickels is " . $money['Nickels'] ." cents.";
```

Furthermore is it even legal to do this:

```
function getselection($selection,$price)
{
```

Have another function or multiple functions inside of the original function defaultcoinload(), I think it is just need a little clarification, thank you, for not flaming.

Comment: Can you submit complete function code? Seems you missed some code lines...

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense to me. Maybe you have to add some other lines of code. What is $insertcoins? $money is a global variable (php need an explicit extension of a function scope, with the global keyword)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks fine.  Perhaps the order of the statements is confusing?  Most engineers would write the function declaration before calling it.  (You have it the other way around.)

Two things I see of concern:

One is an assignment where it looks like an equality comparison makes more sense:

```
if ($money == $insertcoins[$selection])
```

The other is that $money isn't global, so assigning it within the function won't make a visible change outside it.  Fix this by adding `global $money` inside the function.

In summary, try this instead:

```
function defaultcoindload()
{
    /* Have the coin loads up to a maximum of a 1.00 dollar in value:
     * An associative array-ID key is associated with  value (ID is Nickels with value of 20).
     * $money = array("Nickels"=>20, "Dimes"=>10, "Quarters"=>10);
     * The array code for $money above is the same as the array code below,
     * with the difference being the structure and the ID keys can be accessed in a script
     */
    global $money;

    $money['Nickels'] = 20;
    $money['Dimes']   = 10;
    $money['Quarters'] = 4;
    echo "The value of Nickels is " . $money['Nickels'] ." cents.";
}

defaultcoindload();
```

I've removed a lot of things which look like they were for debugging, but after this, you can reference $money.

```
print_r($money);  // show all the money
```

The remaining bugs I leave for you to identify and fix.

Comment: Thanks, it's still a Beta, there are a lot of bugs, I need to focus on really cleaning up the code, the code has dramatically changed from the time that I posted the code to now, thank you.

Comment: Function declaration?

function defaultcoinload();

Call the function

defaultcoinload()
{
}

Comment: A function implementation is "function func() { ... whatever logic needed to implement ... }"  A function declaration is "function func ();"  Note the semicolon.   A function call is "func();"